# Is Corda support state deletion scenario?

Tags: corda

Is corda support state deletion scenario when don't need to use some state (in both dev/prod)
Because I face exception when start node like "class not found exception", It's happen when I delete state class in project and use same old persistence file.

I think it because of state class already insert in VAULT_STATES and it can't find that class when start node.

I expect to have some method that provide state deletion.

**More info**
In Dev side I delete persistence file and of course it's work, but I just worry about Production side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Corda 3, if a node has a state stored as part of a transaction in its transaction storage or in its vault, the node needs to keep the state's class definition on its classpath permanently.

You can delete old transactions and states directly via the node's database, but only if the transactions are not required for transaction resolution. You would do this by dropping rows from the `NODE_TRANSACTIONS` and `VAULT_STATES` tables in the node's database (as well as any custom tables defined by the state's schemas if it is a `QueryableState`). However, if the deleted transactions are later required as part of transaction resolution, your node will throw an error.

Future versions of Corda may provide a mechanism to delete old or "non-current" states and transactions. You can find a discussion of what this process may look like here: https://groups.io/g/corda-dev/topic/20405353.

Comment: Is this still the case with 4.8?

Answer (score 0):

For development purposes you can simply just delete the `persistence.mv.db` file which is the entire H2 database. This will reset your corda node.

Of course don't do that for any production use.

Comment: Thank for answer, So in case I have to change state name how can I do that.

Comment: I just worry that it will have some mistake case happen in production side.