# How Do I Purge Data From Corda?

Tags: corda

One of the business requirements I have been presented with is a potential process to purge customer related data (e.g. under GPDR).

This is a hosted solution where I have admin access on all the nodes.

Is there a way to delete states from Corda.

Can it be done without breaking potential links/references?
i.e. without "corrupting" the database or causing lots of errors when people walk the chain history etc

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018125/is-corda-support-state-deletion-scenario) answer.

Answer (score 0):

At the current stage, we don't support data deletion. You can manually delete the data from the database. However, if you ever need the data for future transaction, your node will throw an error.

This question was also answered here: [Is Corda support state deletion scenario?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018125/is-corda-support-state-deletion-scenario)